# パラメータつきURLのリダイレクトに失敗する

Tags: python, django

現在Djangoを用いてWebアプリケーションを開発しています。

そこで、表題の通りパラメータつきURLのリダイレクトする方法を探しています。

具体的には下記のようなに暗号化されたパラメータをもつURLをそのままリダイレクトしたいです。
現在このままリダイレクトしようとすると "このURLにマッチするルートがない" と言われます。
パラメータがついていないURLでリダイレクトすると成功します。

失敗：
test_app/test/booking_test%3Fcsrfmiddlewaretoken%3DwE7PEfQQwMjMJ3sn60uXO7HyoZT3t3y5cenAaWQoaaNn52lVTxr1kAr89FfQQSMq%26id%3D193

成功：
test_app/test/booking_test

なぜこのようなことをしたいかというと@login_requiredでログイン画面にとび、ログインしたあとその前に行っていた操作をそのまま続けられるような構成にしたいからです。

まだまだ勉強不足で大変恐縮ですが、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

クエリ文字列の「?」や「&」などがエンコードされているからではないですか？
以下のようになると思います。

test_app/test/booking_test?csrfmiddlewaretoken=wE7PEfQQwMjMJ3sn60uXO7HyoZT3t3y5cenAaWQoaaNn52lVTxr1kAr89FfQQSMq&id=193

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
解決することができました。

本当に助かりました。